# OpenLayers 5.3 : Why doesn't draw my poligon?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

This is the code :

```
drawPoligon : function (vertices) {
    debugger;
    var map = peaMap;
    var feature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([vertices])
    });

    var vectorSource= new ol.source.Vector({
        features: [feature ]
    });
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: vectorSource
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

}
vertices = [1253906.08982072, 5430790.35506443, 1253935.16019819, 5430769.74133789, 1253951.90741865, 5430793.82802342, 1253955.42311216........]
```

Format of my coordinates array:

```
[
  [1253906.08982072,5430790.35506443],
  [1253935.16019819,5430769.74133789],
  [1253951.90741865,5430793.82802342],
  [1253955.42311216,5430798.88815272],
  [1253953.91064413,5430800.28580152],
  [1253952.03520923,5430801.40886153],
  [1253945.88800332,5430791.50307534],
  [1253936.62615957,5430797.3914173]
]
```

...The coordinates list isnt full. Only part of it for exposure.

Comment: A polygon on openLayers must include its first coordinates at the end (For the closed connection) So Add your first coordinates again.

Comment: the coordinates entered are not complete, the complete ones are too long to report here. It was only to ask which one was the correct format

Comment: Okey gotchya. Are you faimliar with projections of openLayers? And you could try to zoom to it, maybe it draws it just in totally wrong side. `map.zoomToExtent(vectorLayer.getDataExtent(), false);`

Comment: Also not enough [ ].  Polygons can be multi-ring (i.e. have holes) so even a simple triangle would be [[[1253906.08982072,5430790.35506443],[1253935.16019819,5430769.74133789],[1253951.90741865,5430793.82802342],[1253906.08982072,5430790.35506443]]]

Comment: This guy provided with basic function how to draw a polygon. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002981/openlayers-how-do-i-draw-a-polygon-from-existing-lonlat-points
this is how I do it https://jsfiddle.net/u01q7hcm/
It is most likely to do something with coordinates, its usually sensitive. Make sure you add your layer to the map in the first place.

Comment: My previous comment isn't relevant in this case, since the extra [] are in `ol.geom.Polygon([vertices])`

Comment: You're right mike, I solved by changing the structure of the coordinates and adding the parenthesis []

Comment: To whom it may concern: From my point of view, the processing of the example code in a question corresponding to the given answers or comments makes no sense, especially not for readers who want to track the whole thing later. We all learn from mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

The format [ [lon, lat], … ] is the correct one. With a bigger zoom you can see the result:

```
var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.OSM()
  });

  var vertices = [
    [1253906.08982072, 5430790.35506443],
    [1253935.16019819, 5430769.74133789],
    [1253951.90741865, 5430793.82802342],
    [1253955.42311216, 5430798.88815272],
    [1253953.91064413, 5430800.28580152],
    [1253952.03520923, 5430801.40886153],
    [1253945.88800332, 5430791.50307534],
    [1253936.62615957, 5430797.3914173]
  ];

  var feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon([vertices])
  });

  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: [feature]
  });
  var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        width: 2,
        color: [255, 0, 0]
      })
    })
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [osmLayer, vectorLayer],
    target: document.getElementById("map"),
    view: new ol.View({
      center: [1253950, 5430800],
      zoom: 20
    })
  });
```

Comment: I answered Mike what the problem was